# political-science, politics and law tags, are these synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was reviewing the tags list and came to the following ones with excerpts as:

[political-science](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-science) with 4 questions

> On standards or conventions specific to political science as an academic >discipline, and programs that lead to a degree in this field.

[law](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) with 11 questions

> Academic questions and answers about law and political sciences.

[politics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics) with 3 questions
this tag has no tag excerpt or wiki.

All these tags seem to be synonym and I think politics and political-sciences should merged and the difference of them and the law tag should be declared more or this also should be merged into the previous ones.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the questions tagged with [law](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law), you can see that they're *not* about the academic discipline of political science. Some are about the academic discipline of law, and graduate studies leading to a degree in law; some are about legal issues affecting academicians. None are about political science.

Similarly, of the questions tagged [politics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics), one (which is also tagged political sciences) is about the academic discipline of political science. The others are about interpersonal issues.

So while [law](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) and [politics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics) could do with some improvement, they are *not* synonyms of [political-science](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-science).

To resolve the dual purpose of the [law](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) tag, I've split it into [law](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law), which has the following excerpt:

> On standards or conventions specific to law as an academic discipline, and programs that lead to a degree in this field.

and [legal-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-issues), which has this excerpt:

> On legal issues affecting academicians, including questions on the general legality of certain practices and questions on circumstances brought on by legal issues. Note that Academia.SE, like any SE site, cannot offer specific legal advice; consult a lawyer for such questions.

and retagged a few questions with [law](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) to [legal-issues](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal-issues).

Comment: So it may be better to edit the law tag's excerpt and omit the last part *[...]  and political sciences*. The excerpt needs to be more specific and better written.

Comment: Don't you agree that these tag's excerpts mislead the user? It is so vague where to use each of the tags.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent I agree that 'law' and 'politics' need improvement, as I wrote in my answer. Your question was whether they should be synonyms of 'political-science', and my answer to that question is "No."

Answer (score 5):

### **No, these tags should *not* be merged.**

[law](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) is **never** a synonym for [political-science](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-science); they represent two completely different fields of study. (In general, law faculty would not even work in the same building or "school" within a university as the political science faculty.)

Similarly, [politics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics) does not have the same meaning as [political-science](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-science). You would use the former tag for discussing "power" relationships within a university, a department, or research group; you would *never* use [political-science](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-science) for such a discussion.